# Types of Salesforce community

Tags: community

What are the types of salesforce community and cost of each type?

Comment: Pricing is always negotiable, license types are published: http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing-communities.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce communities basically provide the collaboration between customers, partners, distributors, suppliers and employees. So broadly any organization can own any type of community. Organizations can also provide access to data, content and business process through these communities publically or privately. They provide a social platform through which customers can interact with their favorite vendors. Generally Salesforce supports only following two types of communities:

**Customer Communities:** It provides rich collaboration, consistent branding and mobile access through which even the customers can share their experiences with each other and contact to their representatives as well.

**Partner Communities:** It provides a platform to business partners and a role based power can be added as well. Through these communities the partners can share the relevant information and at the same time can keep some information private as well.

As far as community pricing is concerned, then Salesforce charges two types: one is login based and another is membership based. Moreover the price also depends on the size of the community. Customers can buy either type of membership. Each community has to be purchased separately.

Reference: http://www.janbask.com/salesforce-communities/